# how to change ids and name of cloned elements?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i make a select box and i used clone to make dynamic select boxes but my cloned select boxes  ids and names are the same how to change ids and name of cloned elements?here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
( function($) {
    // we can now rely on $ within the safety of our "bodyguard" function
    $(document).ready( function() {  
    $('#add_button').on('click', function() {
 var selectClone = $('#event_2').clone(true);  // make a copy of select
 $('#some_target').append(selectClone);    // append to clone select

});  

     });
}) ( jQuery );
</script>

<?
$strQuery1="SELECT event_id,event_name from events";
$result1 = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($strQuery1) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
?>
<select id="event_2" name="event_2">
<?  while($ors1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$ors1['event_id'] .'" >' . $ors1['event_name'] . '</option>';
    } 
?>
</select>
<button type="button" value="Add" id="add_button">Add Events</button><br />
<div id="some_target">
</div>
```

i want next cloned element has id and name event_3 and so on how i do this?

Comment: can i use a variable i=2 at first time and after clicking on addevents button it increses 3,4,5 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take care of everything:

```
$('#secondevent').clone().attr('id', 'newid').attr('name', 'newname').appendTo( "#some_target" );
```

> clone, assign new id, assign new name and apppend to element `#some_target`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd6mU/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectClone = $('#event_2').clone(true);
selectClone.attr({ id: 'event_3', name: 'event_3'});
$('#some_target').append(selectClone);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
selectClone.attr('id', 'newValue')
```

Right after appending it to the new location.